# How do I know the input I get from a MsgBox?

Tags: vb6

In VB6 I am trying to find out how to get the input from the user in a MsgBox

Here is my code:

```
Dim myAnswer As Integer

myAnswer = MsgBox("Do you want to buy this upgrade?", vbOKCancel, "Upgrade Description")
```

The MsgBox comes up with an ok and cancel button but I don't know how to tell whether or not they clicked ok or cancel.

Comment: Instead of declaring `myAnswer As Integer`, declare it `As VbMsgBoxResult` that way you'll get intellisense and make it easier to code!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
Dim myAnswer As Integer
myAnswer = MsgBox("Do you want to buy this upgrade?", vbOKCancel, "Upgrade Description")

If myAnswer = vbOK Then
    MsgBox "You clicked 'OK'."
ElseIf myAnswer = vbCancel Then
    MsgBox "You clicked 'Cancel'."
' ...
End If
```

There are 7 constants for the result returned by a `MsgBox` function:

```
Constant    Value   Description
vbOK        1       OK
vbCancel    2       Cancel
vbAbort     3       Abort
vbRetry     4       Retry
vbIgnore    5       Ignore
vbYes       6       Yes
vbNo        7       No
```

### References:

- [MsgBox Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa445082(v=vs.60)).